# How can I insert multiple row in Database?

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the  Method by which I insert the row in my application's database. But its insert only one row. **So what I have to do add multiple rows in database**. This code I had used for the new User Registration in my application.

Thanks in advance.....

```
public void addProductToCart(String username, String password,
        String email, String contact, String bloodgroup, String city, String state) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(colUsername, username);
    contentValues.put(colPassword, password);
    contentValues.put(colEmail, email);
    contentValues.put(colContact, contact);
    contentValues.put(colBloodgroup, bloodgroup);
    contentValues.put(colCity, city);
    contentValues.put(colState, state);
    db.insert(USERTABLE, colUsername, contentValues);
    db.close();

    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "You have registered successfully.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            context.finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you require to insert multiple rows at a time?

Comment: I want it for registering in the application. Because using this code I can register only once. And its totally multi-user application.By this registration done successfully, but data does not go into the database.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is something else that android supports, but my solution will be to build for that a new class with the Fields you need, and then pass as parameter to the addProductToCart method a list of all the objects you want to put. Inside the method do for loop until you get to the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to register multiple users at a time, if u want to add more number of users at a time use the back-end process in you database class.
try to add the values in your code instead of using the user Interface. If you set a on click function to a button then call the method as many times u want with the values you prefer.

Like this,

db.addProductToCart(username1,password1,email1, contact1,bloodgroup1,city1,state1);
db.addProductToCart(username2,password2,email2, contact2,bloodgroup2,city2,state2);
db.addProductToCart(username3,password3,email3,contact3,bloodgroup3,city3,state3);